# GRUB multiboot — load my own application and then Linux

Tags: grub2, grub, multiboot

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to load my own application using GRUB and afterwards load the Linux kernel (vmlinux+initrd). Say I have two menu entries:

```
menuentry "my os" { 
multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin
boot
}

menuentry "linux" {
linux /boot/vmlinuz /dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initrd
boot
}
```

I was wondering whether it is possible to load "my os" and then load "linux". I know that one way to achieve the following is to load *vmlinux* and *initrd* as modules in "my os" and then implement the Linux boot protocol myself. However, I prefer not to do so if I don't have to.

Comment: Are you attempting to leave artefacts of your own OS in memory when Linux boots?  If not then why not have your OS reboot?

Comment: Exactly, I'm trying to leave artifacts of my own application.